# Do all algebraic numbers have a sequence of integers where the ratio of consecutive terms tends to that number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

The most famous example of this is the Fibonacci sequence and the golden ratio.

I feel like this should be obvious. But, if I have an algebraic number say:

$\tan \left(\frac{15π}{16} \right) \approx -0.19891236738$

Which is the root of a irreducible 4th degree polynomial. Can I find a sequence where the ratio of consecutive terms approaches this number?

Can I always do this if I can do it some of the time?

Comment: I think you need to specify some other properties of your sequence.  If you take the sequence {$\alpha^n$} then the ratios tend to $\alpha$ whether it be algebraic or not.  Perhaps you mean "linear regression with integer coefficients"?

Comment: A sequence of integers, please!

Comment: Ok, so take {$\left[\alpha^n\right]$}, at least for $\alpha>1$. I'm pretty sure you want something like "a linear regression with integer coefficients", like the Fibonacci numbers satisfy.  In which case I am fairly sure the answer is  "no" in general...but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: I think Euler supplied a series $a_n$ defined by a linear recurrence (like the Fibonacci numbers!) that gives you an algebraic number, but I think it only can only give you the largest root of your polynomial. (Or the smallest root if you do the ratio the other way.) EDIT: I meant largest in absolute value, assuming it's real.

Comment: @columbus8myhw  Well, if you have a real Pisot number (strictly larger, in norm, than any of its conjugates) then the minimal polynomial is the characteristic function of a sequence of the form we want.  But that's a pretty narrow class of numbers.

Comment: That's a shame. As stated, though, the question is solved by the recurrence $a_{n+1}=\lfloor a_nr\rfloor$ for any $r>1$ (again, algebraic or not).